# This has to do with dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, addition

My code is :

```
cart={}
line=input('Sale: ')
while line:
  parts = line.split()
  name = parts[0]
  number = parts[1]
  cart[name] = int(number)
  number+=number
  cart.update(cart)
  print(number,name, 'sold so far')
  line = input('Sale: ')
```

The question is: I enter a key along with a value. The code then says thet you have sold this value of keys. If you enter the same key in another iteration of the while loop, the value would update to the new value for example:

```
Sale: apples 5
5 apples sold so far
Sale: oranges 2
2 oranges sold so far
Sale: apples 3
8 apples sold so far
Sale:
```

I thought my code would do this but instead when i type: apples 5. It spits out this:

```
Sale: apples 5
55 apples sold so far
Sale:
```

I thought the number+=number was supposed to add to previous variable but instead it prints it a second time. Please explain and help if you can.

Comment: You *are* doing `number+=number`, which, yes, will concatenate it to itself…

Comment: Just curious... what do you expect `cart.update(cart)` to be doing here?

Comment: The problem here is that you do `num += num` while those are still strings and well `'5'+'5'` will give you '55'. Because you only cast the number into int for updating the cart. I would suggest `number = int(parts[0])` to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things here.

You take the number from the input and set it as an integer to the key of the dictionary, overriding whatever is there to begin with. You then take the original string, and add it to itself; so if you input '5' you get '55'. This value has nothing to do with whatever is now in the dictionary. Then, you update cart with itself, which of course makes no changes at all.

When programming, you need to think in terms of logical steps. It may help you to write down the steps in English before writing your code. Here, first, you need to get the current value from the dictionary. Then, convert your input into an int. Next, add your existing value to the new one, and set that value back to the dictionary. Finally, print the new total.

I won't post the exact code for this as the problem is clearly homework, but hopefully this should help you get past your current issue.

Comment: I did it in a flow chart and on paper and found out i had to check if it was an existing value, which I had to use an if statement to check if its already in the dictionary. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two things, number in this case is a string, because it was assigned a string value. To use it as an integer it can be converted as it was done elsewhere in the code:

```
number = int(parts[1])
```

And `number+=number` is equivalent to doing `number+number` and assiging this value back to `number`. In other words, it would be doubling the value of `number` each time, if it were an integer. So, the algorithm should be reviewed if that's not what's intended.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow what @Daniel Roseman suggested, it is always better to try it on your own. But if you are stuck, here is something that might be helpful.

```
cart={}
line=raw_input('Sale: ')
while line:
  parts = line.strip().split()
  name = parts[0]
  number = int(parts[1]) #converting number from string to int

  #this checks if key already exists in the dictionary, if it does not it is created
  if name not in cart:
      cart[name] = number
  #otherwise it is updated
  else:
      cart[name] += number

  #you were trying to do number += number; in your case you did not change number to int variable
  #so number was being treated as string and in context of string += is basically
  #concatenating the string.

  print(str(cart[name]) + ' ' + name + ' sold so far')
  line = raw_input('Sale: ')
```